# Common records for 2 fields in a table?

Tags: db2

I have a Table which has 2 fields say A,B. Suppose A has values a1,a2. 
Corresponding records for a1 in B are 1,2,3,x,y,z.
Corresponding records for a2 in B are 1,2,3,4,d,e,f

I need a a query to be written in DB2, so that it will fetch the common records in B for each record in A (a1 and a2).

So here the output would be :

```
A   B
a1  1
a1  2
a1  3
a2  1
a2  2
a2  3
```

Can someone please help on this?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
SELECT A, B
FROM Table t1
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table t2 WHERE t2.B = t1.B)
    = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t3.A) FROM Table t3)
ORDER BY A, B
```

Comment: No,suppose the field A has one mroe value a3 and it has corresponding B values as m,n,o.
As m,n,o doesnt matches with other B values for a1, a2, the record a3 won't show up.

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood your question. Now I see what want to do, but I need one little clarification to give you a correct answer. If a3 has corresponding B values as m, n, o, 4. How do you want to handle it? Should a3 now appear in the results with the value 4 because it is shared with a2? Or should it not appear in the results because it is not shared with a1 too? In other words, does a value in B have to be shared by all values in A? Or only shared by more than one value in A is enough?

Comment: No, a3 should not appear in result beacuse it is not shared with a1.
So the requirement is the value in B have to be shared by all values in A.

Comment: One last question. Can a value in A have repeated values in B? E.g. a3 has 4, 5, 4?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be 100% accurate as I can't test it out in DB2 so you might have to tweak the query a little bit to make it work.

```
with t(num) as (select count(distinct A) from table) 
select t1.A, t1.B
from table t1, table t2, t
where t1.B = t2.B
group by t1.A, t1.B, num
having count(*) = num
```

Basically, the idea is to join the same table with column B and filter out just the ones that match exactly the same number of times as the number of elements in column A, which indicates that it is a common record out of all the A values.